# Process module list issue when DLL is renamed

Tags: c#, dll

I'm using CreateToolhelp32Snaphot method to list all modules specifically DLLs loaded in a specific process but I just noticed that if loaded DLL is renamed, it is still listed using the initial name (probably the name at the time when DLL loaded in process). Is this a known issue?

```
MODULEENTRY32 modEntry = new MODULEENTRY32();
modEntry.dwSize = (UInt32)Marshal.SizeOf(typeof(MODULEENTRY32));
handleToSnapshot = CreateToolhelp32Snapshot((uint)SnapshotFlags.Module | (uint)SnapshotFlags.Module32, procId);
if (Module32First(handleToSnapshot, ref modEntry))
{
    do
    {
        Console.WriteLine(modEntry.szExePath);
    }
    while (Module32Next(handleToSnapshot, ref modEntry));
}
```

I also tried using EnumProcessModulesEx + GetModuleFileNameEx and I also get same result. I wonder how Process Explorer is able to get the information right, are there any other alternative methods to use?

Comment: This is surely by design.

Comment: It doesn't go look at the disk to see if the file is still there.  Because, as you noted, this cannot be reliable.  Loading a DLL puts a lock on the file data, not the file metadata.  So it might not be there anymore.  It uses the name as recorded internally by the OS loader when it loaded the DLL.

Answer (score 1):

One method would be to directly read the data from the process memory, without using any Win32 function that enumerates the list of modules:

1. Open a handle to the process using [`OpenProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684320(v=vs.85).aspx)
2. Call [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280(v=vs.85).aspx) to get `ProcessBasicInformation` information type and read the `PebBaseAddress` property of the `_PROCESS_BASIC_INFORMATION` structure (Process Environment Block address)
3. Read the PE block using [`ReadProcessMemory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680553(v=vs.85).aspx) from the target process memory (read the [`ldrData`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa813708(v=vs.85).aspx) part)
4. Navigate through the list of loaded modules in memory. See http://sandsprite.com/CodeStuff/Understanding_the_Peb_Loader_Data_List.html for some explanations

That's the most low-level way to get the list of modules I'm aware of, I'm pretty sure Process Explorer does something similar.

But do note it's a real pain to code this right, because you'll have to deal with the 64-bit issues: different memory addresses to use, [WOW64 stuff](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WoW64)...etc. Last but not least: as you're using C#, good luck to get the right P/Invoke signatures of all those (sometimes undocumented) structs/functions :)

---

Edit:
As said in the comments below, this is an alternative low-level method to get the list of modules loaded by a process. But I'm not sure this'll provide the behavior you describe when a module is renamed.

I recommend you to dig into [the source code of Process Hacker](http://sourceforge.net/p/processhacker/code/HEAD/tree/2.x/trunk/) which is an open source project very similar to Process Explorer. I tested PH, it has the same behavior you described. Note: this is C code only, not C#. Look at the `KProcessHacker` directory which is the code of the driver that does all the stuff.

Comment: Why would this result in different behaviour? Do you have any evidence that the end result would be different?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan To be honest, I don't think this'll end up with a different behavior. I'm 95% sure that's how Process Explorer internally enumerates modules, but I think there is another logic involved. This answers the "are there any other alternative methods to use" part of the question, though.

Comment: Please be up front and tell the asker that this immense task won't solve their problem so that the asker doesn't spend days chasing a ghost

Answer (score 0):

In NTFS, filename is a metadata variable stored in the Master File Table.  The MFT also contains a file ID.  When you change a file's name, it does not change the file ID.  The identifier uniquely identifies the file.

Open handles to files are tracked not by their filename but by this unique identifier.

ProcessHacker, Process Explorer and other tools will use [NtQueryInformationFile](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/nf-ntifs-ntqueryinformationfile) from the kernel using the [FILE_INTERNAL_INFORMATION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/ddi/ntifs/ns-ntifs-_file_internal_information) enumerator

This structure contains the member variable `IndexNumber` which is the unique file identifier.

If you want to do the same you will need to be in the kernel and do the same thing:

Find the modules loaded by the process, get the file handle, use the handle to get the IndexNumber via NtQueryInformationFile